# Нестатическая callback функция-член

Tags: c++, winapi

Начал разбираться с `WinAPI`и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
При создании класса (`WNDCLASS`) ему нужно указать функцию-обработчик событий (вероятно это по другому называется, но вы поняли) `LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`. Для чистоты кода я решил вынести все, что связано с этим окном в отдельный класс `MainWindow`.
Тут-то и возникла проблема. Если сделать данную функцию членом класса, то компилятор начинает ругаться на каст:

```
WNDCLASS wc;
...
wc.lpfnWndProc = static_cast<WNDPROC> (wndProc);
```

> Ошибка    C2440   static_cast: невозможно преобразовать "overloaded-function" в "WNDPROC" MyProjectName   c:\...\mainwindow.cpp  22

Перебрал несколько очевидных вариантов решения данной проблемы: сделать функцию статической, дружественной, или использовать лямбду, но дело в том, что в данном окне должны рисоваться объекты(например круг). Соответственно, их экземпляры должны храниться в классе окна, чтобы при `WM_PAINT` просто вежливо попросить их заново нарисоваться и никаких проблем не было.   Тогда это отметает все 3 моих варианта т.к. ни один из них не может напрямую взаимодействовать с нестатическими свойствами класса.
Есть еще 2 варианта, но они ужасные: сделать поля, нужные для перерисовки, статическими или заново создавать их при перерисовки. Даже комментировать это не буду.
Как можно решить эту проблему?
P.S. Вот [код](https://pastebin.com/taccD92Y) реализации класса, если кому-то нужно

Comment: Ну, все равно у вас экземпляр класса должен быть единственным - сделайте его синглтоном, и обращайтесь к нему из `wndProc`. Чем не вариант?

Comment: Если вкратце, то ничего тут сделать нельзя. Обработчик должен как-то находить объект вашего класса, и тогда уже дергать функцию-член.

Comment: @Harry буду честен, проект очень минорный и с `WinAPI` я работать не планирую, но было бы хорошо это все таки сделать. А писать говнокод совесть не позволяет. Да и с синглтоном раньше не сталкивался. Буду очень признателен, если приведете пример как это сделать

Answer (score 3):

Никак нельзя сделать обратный вызов на метод. Можно запоминать для каждого окна Windows указатель на соответствующий ему объект `MainWindow` с помощью функции `SetWindowLongPtr` с параметром `GWLP_USERDATA`и сделать общую функцию `WNDPROC` для всех окон, внутри которой получать с помощью функции `GetWindowLongPtr` этот указатель, преобразовывать к типу `MainWindow*` и запускать на нем какой-то метод.

То есть, вызов метода класса будет осуществляться примерно так:

```
LRESULT MainWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MainWindow *mainwin = static_cast<MainWindow*>(
        GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
    return mainwin->wndProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Тем не менее, я сталкивался с одним показательным случаем, когда это не работает. Моя программа (VST-плагин) получала готовое окно HWND от VST-хоста (сторонняя программа). Все работало, пока я не наткнулся на VST-хост, разработчик которого тоже захотел использовать GWL_USERDATA.

То есть более общий вариант решения - использовать хэш (окно=>объект).

Comment: Можно какой-нибудь простенький пример? Я примерно понял о чем вы, интересная идея, но с `WinAPI` я на вы

Answer (score 1):

> Тем не менее, я сталкивался с одним показательным случаем, когда это не работает. Моя программа (VST-плагин) получала готовое окно HWND от VST-хоста (сторонняя программа). Все работало, пока я не наткнулся на VST-хост, разработчик которого тоже захотел использовать GWL_USERDATA.

Я, собственно, поддерживаю ответ @Alexander Zonov, он верный. Добавлю только как быть ситуации, когда нет возможности использовать `GWL_USERDATA`.

В `WNDCLASS` есть поля:

```
int       cbClsExtra;
int       cbWndExtra;
```

они используются как раз тогда, когда необходимо в объекте класса или в объекте окна хранить **дополнительные данные**. По умолчанию, любое окно уже имеет некоторые данные и мы можем к ним обратиться через `GetWindowLongPtr/SetWindowLongPtr`. Константы `GWLP_xxx` - это всего лишь смещения внутри объекта окна на эти данные. Для того, чтобы их не путать с пользовательскими данными, все служебные смещения сделали отрицательными (просто сдвинули все служебные данные в отрицательную плоскость).

В нашем случае, для обеспечения стабильной работы необходимо зарезервировать в объекте окна размер указателя на объект С++:

```
wc.cbWndExtra = sizeof(void*);
```

после регистрации такого класса окна, любое окно этого класса будет иметь дополнительные 4/8 байт, к которым можно будет обратиться через `GetWindowLongPtr/SetWindowLongPtr`, передавая в качестве смещения значение `0`.

Таким образом, без `GWL_USERDATA` можно вполне обойтись.

Есть еще вариант, когда и этот сценарий не сработает: когда необходимо **наследовать** класс от другого класса, который уже использует дополнительные данные окна. Это достаточно распространенный вариант, за которым даже закреплен устоявшийся термин - **superclassing**.

Но тут тоже все решается довольно просто: надо запомнить значение `cbWndExtra` предка, использовать его в качестве смещения для `GetWindowLongPtr/SetWindowLongPtr`, а перед регистрацией класса окна просто расширить размер объекта окна:

```
GetClassInfo(..., &wc);
...
wc.cbWndExtra += sizeof(void*);
```

Т.е. оконные классы Windows достаточно гибкие. При желании, можно даже полиморфизм организовать, например: хранить в дополнительных данных класса окна указатель на функцию, которую потомки будут переписывать. Этот функционал аналогично работает через `GetClassLongPtr/SetClassLongPtr`.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, хоть и не совсем по делу, вынужден как ответ из-за объема.
Рассказываю о синглтоне. Если у вас есть класс, который должен иметь единственный экземпляр - то запрещаем его копирование, а конструктор делаем закрытым. Этот единственный экземпляр делается статической переменной:

```
class Singleton
{
    Singleton(){};
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;
    ~Singleton(){}
public:
    static Singleton& get()
    {
        static Singleton s;
        return s;
    }
    void out() { cout << "It's me :)\n"; }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Singleton& s = Singleton::get();
    s.out();
}
```

Примерно так. Вы не сможете ни создать, ни скопировать новый объект `Singleton`. Зато любая функция знает, как к нему обратиться - через вызов `Singleton::get()`.

Ну нет дополнительного параметра в обработчике сообщений...

Еще вариант - привязать объект к дескриптору окна, но, по-моему, это хоть и несколько обобщеннее, но ничуть не лучше и уж точно сложнее...
P.S. Пока писал - этот последний способ привязки предложил [в своем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656810/195342) [@Alexander Zonov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/239133/alexander-zonov).